# When we say "established server connection" is it like electric current, i.e. current flowing, connection is active, no current, no server connection?

Tags: networking, webserver

When we connect to a server, like a web server or database server, we need to have an established connection first before we can exchange data.

When we say "**Established Connection**", is the connection similar to electric current, wherein while the current is flowing (active) from **point A** to **point B**, that's the only time the connection ***exists*** or is ***established***? but if no current is flowing from Point A **(client)** to Point B **(server)**, the connection is nonexistent in the context of a server connection?

Comment: There's usually many devices (routers for example) between point A and point B, the "current flowing" analogy is not at all relevant in my opinion

Comment: It's more analogous to a phone call. It's not necessary these days that there's a single point-to-point electrical connection.

Comment: I was going to compare it to a phone call, but ... in the earlier days, a phone call did establish a point-to-point electrical connection. IP is the polar opposite of the telephone system in some ways...

Comment: You actually do not need a connection. Think UDP. You can just throw traffic at whomever. Whether this will result in an answer or even a conversation is another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When we say "Established Connection", is the connection similar to electric current, wherein while the current is flowing (active) from point A to point B, that's the only time the connection exists or is established?

No. This generally refers to a connection made at the 'transport' layer (a TCP connection), which is a purely logical connection that only exists as an entry in each endpoint's "connection table".

For TCP it means the two endpoints have agreed on the sequence numbers and other parameters, but there is not necessarily a continuous flow of packets or anything like that.

Once established, the TCP connection continues to "exist" even when it goes idle, until it's explicitly terminated.

---

(Though your analogy might be correct for certain types of physical (layer 1) connections, e.g. an Ethernet connection, which continuously transmits either a data frame or an idle pattern, but usually that's not what people would refer to by saying 'connection' – instead, at this layer the more common term would be 'link' or 'carrier'.)